# How to use a varibale to call a table and a column in R

Tags: r, variables

I am trying to use different tables in a for loop to produce plots.

I am trying something like this:

```
table_1 <- read.table("sometable1")
table_2 <- read.table("sometable2")
table_n <- read.table("sometablen")

a=1
for(f in args) {

                L <- sub("#", "", readLines(f))
                df <- read.table(text = L, header = TRUE)
                name <- gsub(".txt", "", f)
                name2 <- paste("table_", a, sep="")           
                jpeg(paste(name, ".jpg", sep=""))
                ggplot(df, aes(x=POS, y=Pperbase)) + geom_point() +  geom_vline(xintercept= name2$start, color = "purple", alpha = .05)
                dev.off()

                a=a + 1
            }
```

For each loop, I would like to use two tables, the table df that I am reading from stdin, and to add vertical lines, another table called table_n (where n is going to take numbers from 1 to n). So in the first loop, I would like to use the column "start" from table_1, the second loop the column "start" from table_2, and so on. For this, I am trying to create the name of the tables (table_1, table_1 .. table_n) in a for loop assigning the names to a variable, but it is not working.  Could you please tell me how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
for(f in args) {

            L <- sub("#", "", readLines(f))
            df <- read.table(text = L, header = TRUE)
            name <- gsub(".txt", "", f)
            name2 <- paste("table_", a, sep="")           
            jpeg(paste(name, ".jpg", sep=""))
            print(ggplot(df, aes(x=POS, y=Pperbase)) + geom_point() +   geom_vline(xintercept= eval(as.name(name2))$start, color = "purple", alpha = .05))
            dev.off()

            a=a + 1
        }
```

if I use eval(as.name(variablename)) I can use my variable as a table name.
In addition, I also added print() to have the graph.